# Can I change how long the alarm rings for?

Tags: alarms

I have an alarm set on my phone to encourage me to go to bed at a sensible time. The problem is that if I have left my phone somewhere or go to bed before this time the alarm keeps ringing for an inordinately long time, getting louder and louder, whereas I want it to simply shut up after a short period of time.

Is there any way to configure it to do this? Or any app that could be used to do this?

Comment: No option for now in Win Phone

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the built-in alarm (at least on my Nokia Lumia 925 with WP8).
You can however browse the [Window Phone Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=alarm%20clock), in a simple search for `Alarm Clock` the first result was an app which can be configured differently for each alarm (the link will take you to the US search, the results may vary though, according to your country, model, OS and provider).
If that doesn't work for you, you can use more than one app:
a calendar\to-do\reminders app for those thing we allways forget to do (like going to sleep...), a customizable alarm-clock app for the very important things (like waking up too late in the morning), and finally - the built in alarm clock (because it is already there and very simple to quickly set).

Comment: I add look into alarm clock apps; however it seems none of them can properly play an alarm unless the app is left running.

Comment: @JackAidley That is because of WP restrictions, some apps can play the built in alarm when turned off, not the sound you set though. however, keeping it open in the background should not be a problem usually, not every app drains battery too quickly...